# How to merge multiple Mac excel files all with headers that are the same but out of order

Tags: microsoft-excel, macos, csv

I am using a Mac. My excel files have headers that match but are out of order. They all start with a header named "query" and then it gets mixed after that.

Here are some header examples:

- query|email|facebookUrl|twitterUrl|phoneNumber|timestamp|instagramUrl|error|linkedinUrl|youtubeUrl
- query|facebookUrl|linkedinUrl|phoneNumber|timestamp|youtubeUrl|email|error|instagramUrl|twitterUrl
- query|email|facebookUrl|instagramUrl|timestamp|linkedinUrl|youtubeUrl|phoneNumber|twitterUrl|error

I can use Terminal to merge all csv files with `cat *.csv >combined.csv`. But it doesn't work well because all the headers are out of order.

Any ideas what I can do?

Comment: So if each file's columns were in the same order, then your cat would work? If so, how would you determine the correct order? And is it guaranteed that each file has the same headings (albeit in a different order)?

Comment: Yes, if each file had columns in the same order the cat would work. There is no correct column order, any order will be fine. If an order is needed for processing them maybe alphabetically would work. And yes, it's guaranteed each file has the same headings (but out of order).

Comment: You could write a VBA routine that reads in the data into a VBA array; sort the columns into the desired order; then write it to the worksheet.  If you have Office 365 and access to a Windows machine, you can use Power Query.  You would author the query in the Windows machine with VBA, then transfer the VBA code to the Mac. *(Office 365 on the MAC can run Power Query, but cannot author it)*  See [Use Power Query in Excel for Mac](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-power-query-in-excel-for-mac-7b2f337d-e7d2-4fdf-bf00-3dfbb1e5e9c5)

Comment: If you can install the command-line tool miller (visit the link in the answer below and look for 'mac' to find two methods of installing) then this will solve your problem with just a single line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use a CSV aware tool. A great one is [Miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller)

If you have in example these 3 CSV files

```
#input_01.csv
a,b,c
0,2,5

#input_02.csv
b,a,c
0,2,5

#input_03.csv
b,a
0,2
```

you can run `mlr --csv unsparsify ./input_0*.csv >./output.csv` to have

```
+---+---+---+
| a | b | c |
+---+---+---+
| 0 | 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 0 | 5 |
| 2 | 0 | - |
+---+---+---+
```

Comment: +1 Simple and effective

Comment: Thank you! Simple. Easy. Works a charm. Some of my files had headers with blank cells underneath (i.e. null data) and that was causing problems. So I added the `--ragged` argument making the full command to `mlr --csv --ragged unsparsify *.csv >./output.csv`. Hope that helps anyone else that passes by.

Comment: Is it possible to use Miller to remove blank rows? I can't find anything in the docs so far, but it is quite extensive so I have probably overlooked it somewhere.

Comment: @TinyTiger yes, but please create new question, tagged with "miller"

Comment: There is no existing tag for Miller and creating a new tag requires 300 rep points, which I don't have. Regardless, here is the question (without the tag): https://superuser.com/questions/1667022/how-to-delete-blank-rows-in-csv-files-using-the-miller-command-line-tool

Comment: @TinyTiger here you can use Miller tag https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: New question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68618018/how-to-delete-blank-rows-in-csv-files-using-the-miller-command-line-tool

Answer (score 0):

If your files are beastly in size, look into Power Query. I do not personally currently have the skills with it to reorder your columns in a particular order, though I could reorder them alphabetically... I think). So I will not talk about how to achieve it here, at least not today.

It can do some amazing things (amazing to one used to being limited by Excel's limits, and not widely enough experienced at VBA to do more than marginally complicated things). It can definitely do the job, this much I know, though I do not think I'd get it done soon.

However, if the files are not beastly in size so that a **VERY** simple formula approach could do the work without choking your computer to a halt, or Excel at least, then the following is a very simple approach indeed.

I did not see whether the files that you use must continue their existence exactly like they are now or if they can be modified. If they must stay as is, make a subdirectory and copy all of them to it. If changing them is fine, that's easier, a wee bit since there is no copying of the files, but if the files will continue to be used, and simply reordering the columns will cause no problems, it would be very much nicer to change them so that they never need changed again in the future. "One and done" as they say.

To reorder the columns without any amount of work to speak of, simply use the following formula:

```
=INDEX($I$1:$O$4,SEQUENCE(ROWS($I$1:$O$4)),MATCH($A$1:$G$1,$I$1:$O$1,0))
```

(For the formula, I put a 6 column by 4 row table in A:G, then another in I:O with the same headings but they are of mixed order relative to the A:G table.)

`INDEX()` is given the table you wish reordered, I1:O4 in this case. To tell it to use all the rows, we use `SEQUENCE()` with one parameter (since "rows" or output is its first parameter, we need no more). That parameter is the number of rows in the table you need reordered. Using sequence lets you give it either a range address like I did, a Named Range (really why one would use it so), **OR** just the number of rows. After all, most tables you get that just knowing the right side of the range, eh? Or maybe just subtract some value for rows above it. Only with a Named Range do you really have to do anything other than just say something like "Hmm... I1:O4... must be 4 rows in it so I'll just enter 4...".

The final part is the good part:  the ordering of the columns. `INDEX()` lets you rearrange columns and/or have them appear more than once. If you knew the order you needed for all the files, you might just enter something like `{4,2,19,7,...}` to tell it, but you do not know. They could be any order and each different.

But if you use `MATCH()`, you can let Excel do the work for you for all the different orders. You tell `MATCH()` to use the headings for one file, whatever one, doesn't matter, but you use that file's heading order for ALL the files you open and rearrange. So match looks for each one of them in the current file's headings and feeds the order of them it finds back to `INDEX()` which then reassembles your data in the same heading order as the file you chose to be the source of order.

Even better, almost, is the fact that the formula produces a 2-D SPILL array, so copying the formula to a single cell will produce the entire output table.

Since you will do it in a file that can be saved once the work is done (either a copied set or the originals, one way or the other you are going to work with files that can be changed and saved), you next want to select the entire output, then copy and `Paste|Special|Values` to have just data, not formula output. Then delete the original material leaving only the output table. Save. Move on to the next one.

A nicety, if you plan to do it on the originals and they will see further use, would be to select the original table and copy, then `Paste|Special|Formats` to keep the table formatting on the output table. Even do `Paste|Special|Column widths` to keep the same look and feel.

I guess you won't need the column widths, come to think of it, since you seem to be planning to join CSV files together... Pretty much NONE of the formatting will matter. Still, if you do use live files and you do expect to use them in the future, do the formatting steps before deleting the original tables. Save as Excel files, then a CSV copy. I'm guessing maybe they're already CSV files, so no worries about any of it, but keep it in mind for other uses of the approach.

Anyhow, open the first file in the list, copy this formula into it and adjust addressing as needed, then copy the formula cell, open the second file in the list and paste. Do the above to change it to data, delete the old, then save back in the same CSV format. Rinse and repeat until all the files have been fixed up. Then do your joining up of them.

Even nicer, if you are good enough with VBA, open a new file, name and save it (as a macro file, so .xlsm), write a macro to chunk through the files in the directory, adding the formula to each, changing the output to data only, deleting everything to the left of it so the first cell of the output is A1, and saving each as a CSV. Save this new file again. Then roll it out and let it run.

Comment: To reorder the columns into any particular order, merely create a `List` of columnNames in the desired order.  Then, using the `Table.ReorderColumns` command, use that list for the second argument.

Comment: Thanks! I knew the way would be straightforward.