# How to delete blank rows in csv files using the Miller command line tool?

Tags: command-line, csv

I have a csv file (on Mac) with many blank rows.

I am using the [Miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) command-line tool for other processes and would like to remove blank rows also using that tool.

I can't find anything in the docs so far, but it is quite extensive so I may have overlooked it somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb is [`skip-trivial-records`](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-verbs.html#skip-trivial-records):

```
mlr --csv skip-trivial-records input.csv >output.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with other tool (`grep`) you can do it on this way:

```
grep -v ^$ input_file >output_file
```